# MI minijuego de Python, el cual debería funcionar no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x

hoy he estado intentando optimizar un minijuego que hice en mi primer día de Python, para hacer el código más corto porque yo creo que es demasiado largo para un minijuego así, bueno, pues Python se cierra cada vez que lo corro, y no sé por qué, a mi vista todo se ve como que funciona, y Visual Studio Code no detecta ningún error igual que VS Community 2017, así que no se que hacer, alguien me puede ayudar? Aquí está el código:

```
import os, sys
import random

def cls():
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        os.system('cls')
    if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        os.system('clear')
n = int(0)

li = int(input("Cuantas vidas quieres tener? (MAX. 5) ")
if (li > 5):
    print("Eso supera el maximo de vidas, las vidas serán 5.")
    li = 5
    gameMini()

#Functions
def gameMini():
    if li <= 0:
        print("Perdiste..... pulsa ENTER para salir")
        input("")
        exit()
        
    cls()
    
    print("Y = Tu")
    print("  W")
    print("A Y D")
    print("  S")
    print("Muevete con WASD luego ENTER")
    loca = str(input(""))
    cls()
    
    if loca == "w":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "a":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "s":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "d":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if int(n == 1):
        li = li - 1
        print(li)
        print("Perdiste una vida, pulsa ENTER para continuar")
        input("")
        gameMini()
    if int(n == 0):
        li = li - 0
        print(li)
        print("No perdiste nada, pulsa ENTER para continuar")
        input("")
        gameMini()
gameMini()
```

Gracias.

Comment: El código tiene errores de sintaxis. Revisalo

Comment: Por favor, me puedes decir donde? Sigo siendo un poco novato en Python y no he visto ningún error

Comment: Línea 11. Abres dos paréntesis pero solo cierras uno.

Comment: Aparte de eso, la función `gameMini()` intenta modificar una variable global sin haberla declarado, lo que dará problemas porque será considerada local. Mejor le pasas `li` como parámetro a la función para evitar el uso de variables globales

Comment: Aparte de lo anterior, el código tiene muchas otras cosas mejorables, pero no es este el objetivo de la pregunta, creo

Comment: Gracias :)         .................................................